# Get user input via for loop for python script in a Flask application

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create a very simple one-page Flask application for a python script that I have. The script requires multiple user inputs in a for-loop with the number of loops being user input as well.

Here is the code in my script to make it more clear:

```
def shared_books():
    import requests as re
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import time

    num_lists = int(input('Enter the number of lists you would like to search:'))
    urls = []
    page_counts = []

    for i in range(num_lists):
        urls.append(input(f'Enter the url for list {i + 1}:'))
        page_counts.append(int(input(f'Enter the number of pages for list {i + 1}:')))
```

I want a simple HTML that will ask the user for the number of lists, then the URL and page count for each list as is shown in my function. Then it will run the entire function.

The HTML code I have right now is super simple and I don't want much else outside of the input parts:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Goodreads-App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to my app!</h1>
        <<p>This app will allow you to see books that are
           shared between multiple lists on goodreads</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please let me know how I can set up this application!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: you are supposed to interract with flask using http requests, not input !

Comment: @KlausD. Nothing yet I don't know where to start!

Comment: @CyrilJouve Okay thanks, I will look into using HTTP requests! Will report back after I try that out

Comment: I know this is off topic and ridiculously goody-two-shoes but goodreads have an api for this sort of thing, which they would probably rather you used than web scraping

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I suggest you take a look at the [Flask docs](https://flask-doc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). You are doing it right in terms of having a view function, but the `input()` python keyword doesn't work like that in Flask. Instead, you should render an html template which you can then put your form input field into. Here is an example:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template

#flask initialising stuff, read docs for info

@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")
```

Flask runs on your computer's local server "localhost", which is not publicly accessible. It conventionally runs on port 5000, which gives the name "localhost:5000".

When someone visits "localhost:5000/home", flask will look for a file called "home.html" in a pre-designated templates folder – the default is a directory called "templates" which you should put your html files into.

So if this is your "home.html" file:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Goodreads-App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to my app!</h1>
        <p>This app will allow you to see books that are
           shared between multiple lists on goodreads</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

When you load the page associated with a specific function, it will return a template which is rendered as html. The above should look something like this:

[image: flask home page]
And that is how to start.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers! I haven't quite solved the previous issue but have approached it from a different angle which is working now! I will potentially post again if I don't solve it.

I am using flask forms to do what I was trying.